# Send a parameter with Http.GetJsonAsync

Tags: json, blazor, webapi

I have the following code in a Blazor app that calls an API and retrieved a list of Items based on the user id parameter.

The Http.GetJsonAsync does not seem to allow me to enter a parameter. How do I specify the userid  variable as the parameter?

**Calling the API**

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    userid = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("userid");

    myTrades = await Http.GetJsonAsync<ItemForTrade[]>("api/Trading/GetTradesForUser");        
}
```

**The API code**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<List<ItemForTrade>> GetTradesForUser(string userid)
{
    return await tradingService.GetTradesForUser(userid);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HttpGet` passes parameters through the URL,so it's as easy as adding `?userid=value` to the URL like this:

```
myTrades = await Http.GetJsonAsync<ItemForTrade[]>("api/Trading/GetTradesForUser?userid=" + userid);
```

Comment: valid `$"api/Trading/GetTradesForUser/{userid}"` ?

Comment: ***parameters*** through the URL not encripted. Be careful pass a ***password***.